# How to fill a form with fetched data from an API?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I made user information page and users can change and update their information. I want to display the data and fill form inputs automatically with get request data.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row gutters">
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="account-settings">
                <div class="user-profile">
                  <div class="user-avatar">
                    <img src="../../assets/people/a2.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="profile_avatar">
                  </div>
                  <h5 class="full_name">B</h5>
                  <h6 class="email">bngu@a.org</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row gutters">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                  <h6 class="mb-2 text-primary">Profil Detayı</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="first_name">İsim</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="İsim" :value="first_name" required :disabled="!isEditable">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="last_name">Soyisim</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Soyisim" v-model="last_name" :disabled="!isEditable">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" :value="username" disabled>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" v-model="email" disabled>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gsm_number">Telefon</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gsm_number" placeholder="Telefon" v-model="gsm_number" :disabled="!isEditable">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                  <label for="gsm_number">Şifre</label>
                  <b-input-group>
                    <b-form-input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Şifre" v-model="password" :disabled="!isEditable"></b-form-input>
                    <template #append>
                      <b-button v-b-modal.modal-prevent-closing variant="default" @click="passwordModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> </b-button>
                      <b-modal
                          id="modal-prevent-closing"
                          ref="modal"
                          title="Şifre Değiştir"
                      >
                        <form ref="form" @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit">
                          <b-form-group
                              label="Mevcut Şifre"
                              label-for="password"
                              invalid-feedback="Mevcut şifrenizi giriniz"
                          >
                            <b-form-input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"
                            ></b-form-input>
                          </b-form-group>
                          <b-form-group
                              label="Yeni Şifre"
                              label-for="new_pass"
                              invalid-feedback="Yeni şifrenizi giriniz"
                          >
                            <b-form-input type="password" class="form-control" id="new_pass"
                            ></b-form-input>
                          </b-form-group>
                          <b-form-group
                              label="Yeni Şifre Doğrulama"
                              label-for="new_pass_con"
                              invalid-feedback="Yeni şifrenizi tekrar giriniz"
                          >
                            <b-form-input type="password" class="form-control" id="new_pass_con"
                            ></b-form-input>
                          </b-form-group>
                        </form>
                      </b-modal>
                    </template>
                  </b-input-group>
                </div>
              </div>
                  <div class="inline">
                    <b-button v-if="!isHidden" v-on:click="isHidden = true" variant="default" @click="editProfile"><i class="fa fa-pencil" id="editButton"></i> </b-button>
                    <b-button  variant="default" @click="saveProfile"><i class="fa fa-save" id="saveButton"></i> </b-button>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Is there an option to just call userinfo and fill all inputs? Or should I do the same thing `this.username = res.data` for all my inputs like first_name, last_name etc.? Here is my methods:

```
<script>

import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name:'ProfilePage',
  data(){
    return{
      isEditable:false,
      isHidden:false,
      username:"",
      userinfo:[]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    getProfile(){
      if(this.$route.params.id == undefined ||  this.$route.params.id == null){
        axios.get(`/v1/management/update_user/`)
            .then(res=>{console.log(res)
              this.username = res.data

            })
      }else {
        axios.get(`/v1/management/update_user/${this.$route.params.id}`)
            .then(res=>{console.log(res)
              this.username = res.data
            })
      }
    },
    editProfile(){
      this.isEditable = !this.isEditable
    },
    saveProfile(){

    },
    passwordModal(){

    },
    checkResetPassword(){
      if(this.new_pass!== this.new_pass_con){
        this.$toasted.error("Şifreler farklı!"),{
          action: {
            text: 'Kapat',
            onClick: (e, toastObject) => {
              toastObject.text("").goAway(10);
            }
          }
        }

      }else {
        this.$toasted.success("İşlem başarılı!"),{
          action: {
            text: 'Kapat',
            onClick: (e, toastObject) => {
              toastObject.text("").goAway(10);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getProfile()
  }
}


</script>
```

[image: here I get the data but its not the actual data.]

Comment: Did you tried a `v-model` or a `:value` on the input to bring back the value of `this.userInfo`?

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" :value="username" required disabled>
I tried like this but didn't work

Comment: You're doing `this.userInfo =` and not `this.username =` after your axios call so seems legit.

Comment: Should I write `this.` for my every input?

Comment: Depends on what you want but I guess so? Hard to say without a more detailed example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" :value="userinfo.username" disabled>
      <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" :value="userinfo.email" disabled>
      <input id="website" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="website" :value="userinfo.website" disabled>
      <button @click="fetchUser">fetch some user</button>
      <p>Actual user info object: <pre>{{ userinfo }}</pre></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      userinfo: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchUser() {
      const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
      const data = await response.json()
      this.userinfo = data
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

---

This kind of basic code should totally work

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" :value="username" disabled>
      <button @click="fetchUser">fetch some user</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: 'nick'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchUser() {
      const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
      const data = await response.json()
      this.username = data.username
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is [a playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

Comment: I get the data inside my input form but now It seems [object Object]

Comment: @su-wanKenobi probably because you're missing something. Like `object.username` or `object.data.username` I don't know. Inspect it with your devtools or a `console.log + JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-model` to bind the data into the form fields. For demo purpose instead of `v-for`, I am directly binding the value based on index.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      userInfo: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getProfile();
  },
  methods: {
    // Just for demo I am directly assigning the mock response in userInfo array. You can replace that with API call response.
    getProfile() {
        this.userInfo = [{
        username: 'alpha'
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  UserName : <input type="text" v-model="userInfo[0].username">
</div>
```

Comment: i edit my code, can you check it?

Comment: Yes i checked, You are getting [object object] because you are assigning an object in `this.username` it should be a string as `v-model` directive does not work with objects directly.